# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

I am working with a tutorial on Youtube entitled:

> How to make a Java "Tower Defence" game? Part 1 of 3! - "Layouting"

the coding was working but now this error keeps popping up

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

when I run my code can anyone help me please? Here is my code

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Store {
    public static int shopWidth = 8 ;
    public static int buttonSize = 32;

    public Rectangle[] button = new Rectangle[shopWidth];

    public Store() {
        define();   
    }

    public void define(){
        for(int i=0;1<button.length;i++){
            button[i] = new Rectangle((Screen.myWidth/2)-((shopWidth*buttonSize)/2), 10, buttonSize, buttonSize);
        }
    }
    public void draw(Graphics g){
        for(int i=0;1<button.length;i++){
            g.fillRect(button[i].x, button[i].y, button[i].width, button[i].height);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a more detailed stack trace? In addition, it would be helpful for you to do some experimentation, search for other cases of that error (basically paste it into your search engine of choice) and provide some way of reproducing the problem (like giving some data that you used in the program that resulted in that error).

Answer (score 1):

It is a simple typo.

Try `i<button.length` instead of `1<button.length`...

As it is now the loop does not end until the exception occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You implemented `1<button.length` in both the `for` loops. In this case `1` is always less than `button.length` because its length is `shopWidth` that is 8. And you can't store infinite values in an array of length 8.

You should write it as `i<button.length`